# in Budhism, what would happen with a soul in a eventually case of succesfull cryogenic reanimation?

Tags: reincarnation

there is some text that speaks something related about, what would happen with a soul in a eventually case of succesfull cryogenic resucitation? i know this is a very new theme, but, if reincarnation is possible, what happens when that last body reach a reanimation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Once you die the stream of consciousness arises in another body. This is another person. You cannot bring back this stream of consciousness to the same / previous body.`

Once the consciousness has left the body regardless of it being frozen or not the body is dead. The body cannot be made alive again. In believe in the process of freezing the body would at some point die as heat is needed to sustain life.

Also in Buddhism there is concept of no soul. So what question like what happens to the soul is irrelevant. I believe once procedure is done you are simply dead and just a lump of matter devoid of any life faculty.

There are stories of dead getting reanimated, but this is due to other entities repossessing the body and not that the person has become alive again. This appears in the Vinaya, exact location I forget, but there is a rule not to take clothes from a fresh dead body for robes until some lapse of time, if I remember right. See note on Vetala-panka-vimsati [BRAHMA-GALA SUTTA](https://arhatbuddhism.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/buddha-brahmagala-sutta/) and p252, [THE IMPERIAL GAZETTEER OF INDIA: THE INDIAN EMPIRE VOL II HISTORICAL](http://www.burmalibrary.org/docs20/Imperial_Gazetteer_of_India-Vol.02-1909-to-s.pdf).

In case of these possessions the body does not live again as the entity which walks in does have a own subtle body but is controlling the **dead** body. For this to happen is very rare as you have to be a very powerful entity to do something like this. There are some less powerful entities which can do an illusion of being actually moving. That is why when you are meditating on a corpse it is advised to concentrate also on position of the corpse relative to objects around the corpse before starting so you can reassess that this is not the case such illusion comes to your mind.

Also following question might be of interest: [Where in the Pali Canon are there Discussions on Reanimated Corpse?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18241/where-in-the-pali-canon-are-there-discussions-on-reanimated-corpse)

Comment: Suminda, the asker's question is not very clear but I feel like we should assume that if a body is cryogenically frozen successfully, then it is not death.

Comment: See if this is now more incline from what can be inferred from the question?

Answer (score 1):

If someone was somehow reanimated then I suppose it would be like there was never a death. The resurrected person would be born in the human realm yet again then again and again in every  moment because a being is always changing in every moment, moment by moment. The last moment person is dead and the new present moment person is reborn. The whole frozen death thing would have been just another moment.